# Can't remove mysql completely

Tags: 20.04, mysql, software-uninstall

I tried many times to completely remove MySQL from my system without success. I get these errors:

[image: Photo error 1]

[image: Photo error 2]

I also tried other commands without success. What should I do?

Here is the output of `apt list --installed | grep mysql`:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

default-libmysqlclient-dev/focal,now 1.0.5ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
libmysqlclient-dev/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [installed]
libmysqlclient21/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [installed]
libmysqlclient21/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 i386 [installed]
libpocodatamysql62/focal,now 1.9.2-3ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
mysql-client-8.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [installed]
mysql-client-core-8.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [installed]
mysql-common/focal,focal,now 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 all [installed]
mysql-server-8.0/now 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3]
mysql-server-core-8.0/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [installed]
```

Here I am inside `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` and I searched for "mysql" and I see these files:

[image]

Should I delete them or is it a bad idea? If I delete them, will I be able to uninstall everything related to MySQL?

Using this command:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Please edit to post the output of `apt list --installed | grep mysql`. Please post the full error message and format it as code instead of adding images.

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove a package, we can use the `apt purge` command with arguments such as `--autoremove` to clear off the dependencies along with their parent packages. In your specific case, I don't think `apt purge` will work as `dpkg` is throwing errors with the pre-installation script. It seems like you have manually removed some files or directories.

- Use the `dpkg` command with the `-P` argument to forcefully purge the package.

For forcefully purging the package.

1. Since removing packages can be destructive, print the list of the package that will be removed:

   ```
   dpkg -l | awk  '{print $2}' | grep -i mysql | grep -v lib
   ```

   Check if any important package is being removed. If everything seems fine, proceed to step 2.
2. Purge the packages:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -P  --force-all $(dpkg -l | awk  '{print $2}' | grep -i mysql | grep -v lib)
   ```

This should completely remove MySQL. Then run a force install:

```
sudo apt -f install
```